# Help remembering the name of an adventure?

Tags: published-adventures, adnd-2e, product-identification

I have been playing tabletop RPG's since the mid-1990's. One of the first adventures I ever played the DM got from a magazine. I would really like to figure out what the adventure was called so I can find a copy.

Here is what I remember.

- This was approx 1995 or 1996 so the adventure would have been from around that time or earlier.
- At the time we were playing D&D 2nd ed. So this adventure was most likely for that system.
- It was from a magazine. I'm not positive, but I don't think it was Dungeon magazine.
- The DM made us roll up characters based on ourselves – I don't know if this was actually part of the adventure or he just thought it was a good idea because there was almost no combat or anything.
- Almost all of the adventure was solving puzzles.
- If you died you got resurrected. There was some way to keep track of how many lives you used.
- There were white feathers given to players. I cannot remember if you got a white feather for dying or for successfully solving a puzzle.

I would appreciate if anyone could point me to this adventure.

Comment: Holy unexpected flashback, Batman! I've played this adventure. I didn't know it was a pre-made one. The feather tokens were given for passing the puzzles. There was a room with swinging spiked pendulums that you had to cross, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure there were swinging pendulums. And an area where with a sign that said something like "peace" and the monster would let you pass if you left your weapons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is Code of the Rats from [Shadis Issue #21](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=5966). It's by Dave Dollar and ran around 30 pages according to the [Shadis Index](http://www.erzo.org/shannon/gaming/indices/shadis.txt). (Search for 'rats'.) It's also referred to as "From Spuds to Studs" in [RPG.net's article index](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?articleid=1295).

(Billed on the cover as "The Only Introductory Fantasy Adventure You'll Ever Need.") It was:

- Published in 1995.
- In Shadis Magazine, rather than Dungeon.
- System agnostic, but easily adaptable to AD&D.
- Full of different puzzles with either very little or no combat.
- It used white feathers gained from solving puzzles as 'extra lives'
- Even if you ran out of feathers, character death wasn't final. (I wish I could recall how or why.)

I didn't have the adventure, but I borrowed it from a friend. I played it myself and ran it as a starting adventure for a new group of AD&D 2nd Edition players in high school. I don't believe that it originally contained characters based on the players, as I think we used regular characters for it.

I tried to find some more information about it online, but didn't come up with any descriptions or reviews of it after a quick googling.

Comment: I'm trying to get a hold of this to confirm but that sounds right. Kenzerco has pdfs of the first 8 issues for sale on their website but nothing later.

Comment: The three magazines our local shop carried when I was run through this adventure were *Dragon*, *Dungeon*, and *Shadis*, so it's very likely. It's also highly unlikely for two such adventures to have been published at that time.

Comment: I've ordered a copy on amazon but I'm marking this correct in the meantime. Thankyou very much.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that it's correct. I just wish I could find more info to back it up. Enjoy the adventure!